# Disabling Team Foundation Server extensions in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

We're using Visual Studio 2010 (Premium edition if it matters), and pretty happy with it. However, We're *never* going to use the TFS features that's included in the IDE.  (We're using Jira and Subversion, as it's not just Visual Studio that we work with, but also IntelliJ and a couple other IDE's.)

Is there any way to disable the TFS portions of the IDE?  It's not a big deal or anything, just for the sake of "keeping things neat."

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio 2010, go to `Tools->Options`  In the list, select `Source Control.`  Set your `Current source control plug-in:` to `None`

Answer (score 0):

The main "TFS" parts of the IDE are in Team Explorer - Just don't install it.

Anything else you don't want/use, I'd advise you to simply ignore - VS has support for hundreds or even thousands of different things that you will probably never use, and you can't easily "clean" them all away.

In my experience the more you alter your installation of Visual Studio the more problems you will have with it. Every custom Option you set is another thing you have to repeatedly set every time you get a new PC or install a new VS. (Although it has improved a lot since import/export options became available and reliable). I used to spend about half a day setting up a visual studio to "work well", and now I just install it and use it. Ultimately I found that it was easier to just adjust my working practices (e.g. by relearning a few keyboard shortcuts etc) than to try to bend VS to my will.

Comment: Yes, we didn't install the additional bits that come with TFS itself (we have access to it via MSDN but never installed it)  I guess the parts I'm referring to are built into the IDE itself, and there's no additional TFS options on the IDE's installation.  It's kind of what I figured, thanks for confirming my suspicions.  Again, it's not a big deal, just for the sake of removing some extra clutter.

And I completely agree about "bending Visual studio to your will".. I love the 2010 IDE, but sometimes it has a mind of its own, and when it comes down to a battle of wills, I typically lose :D

Comment: Your comment, Jason, was true of TFS & VS 2008, but not 2010.